# Get each screen resolution and zoom factor

Tags: c#, screen-resolution, dpi, multiscreen

I'm trying to get every screen resolution (ex : 1920x1080) and zoom factor (ex : 125% or 120 dpi), without needing to move the application from screen to screen.

I've tried a lot of class/methods, but none gave me the correct result for my setup (Windows 10, primary screen is 1920x1080 zoom 125% and secondary screen (on the right) is 1920x1080 zoom 100%).

`System.Windows.Forms.Screen` gives those results :
- 1920x1080 resolution for 1st screen (ok)
- 2400x1350 resolution for 2nd screen (not ok, should be 1920x1080)

Same results with http://www.wpftutorial.net/ScreenResolutions.html

With PInvoke, `shcore.dll`'s `GetDpiForMonitor()` gives those results :
- 120 for 1st screen (ok)
- 120 for 2nd screen (not ok, should be 96)

Do you have any idea how I can do that and have correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: in the registry, the resolution is correct.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Hardware Profiles\*\CONTROL\VIDEO\*\*
```

In there, you can find your current screens with `Attach.ToDesktop` = 1.
Then, you can use `DefaultSettings.XResolution`, `DefaultSettings.YResolution`, `Attach.RelativeX` and `Attach.RelativeY` to find screen resolutions and positionning.

To find the zoom factor, either use `GetDpiForMonitor()` if the resolution from registry is the same as the resolution from `System.Windows.Forms.Screen` or get the ratio from both and multiply it by 96.